# What's the migration path from APC to OPcache?

Tags: php, apc, opcache

What's the proper way to upgrade php and the APC caching mechanism to the newer/better OPcache? Is there a specific tool or reconfiguration script?

Comment: Best way is to decouple your cache storage, so that it would be easy to switch not only from APC to OPCache, but from whatever to whatever (Redis to Memcached etc). You should simply define an `interface` that they must implement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best place to start would be with the official OPcache resource: http://php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php

Comment: Peter, the first thing to note is that APC does data and Opcode caching, but OPCache only does the latter.  You also need to install APCu is your applications use APC data caching.  At an application level its pretty transparent unless you have apps which use the APC management calls and these will need to be rewritten to use the OPCache equivalents.